# how to by pass Python Selenium undetected_chromedriver website only load table rows if window focus

Tags: selenium-webdriver

hello i am trying to webscrap https://coinmarketcap.com/nft/collections/?page=1
with undetected_chromedriver selenium

i used :

```
 driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {}-200)".format(pagescrollindex))
```

in a loop to scroll down and it works the row fill with data when i have the window open/infocus
if i open any other window that cover it the rows are left empty

 anyone run in to this problem and know how to by pass this javascript function requirement

code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
import mysql.connector
from random_user_agent.user_agent import UserAgent
from random_user_agent.params import SoftwareName, OperatingSystem
import undetected_chromedriver as uc

index=0
while True:
    options = uc.ChromeOptions() 
    options.headless = False


    driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True, options=options) 
    time.sleep(4)
    try: 
        print("get page:","https://coinmarketcap.com/nft/collections/?page={}".format(index))
        url="https://coinmarketcap.com/nft/collections/?page={}".format(index)
        driver.get(url)
        if index==lastpage:
            index=1
        trcount=0
        retrycount=0
        pagescrollindex=500
        while trcount<100:
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {}-200)".format(pagescrollindex))
            pagescrollindex=pagescrollindex+1000
            time.sleep(3)
            htmlpage=driver.page_source
            curcount=htmlpage.count('<tr>')
            print("current count:",curcount)
            if trcount!=curcount:
                trcount=curcount
                retrycount=0
                continue
            if retrycount==5:
                pagescrollindex=-5000
                print("scroll back up")
                driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, {}-200)".format(pagescrollindex))
                pagescrollindex=200
                retrycount=0

                #break
            else:
                retrycount=retrycount+1
                continue

        print()
```

Comment: post your code, for a minimal reproducible example. Do you expect, someone will just write an entire script for you ?

Comment: added the code sorry

Comment: `lastpage` is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest (and maybe also most accurate) way to scroll is using javascript's `scrollIntoView` which let you scroll to a specific element.

So as first thing get the list of all the empty rows. Then scroll down to the first empty, wait a second and get again the list of empty rows. Then repeat the process until there are no more empty rows.

```
trs_empty = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbody>tr[class]')
while len(trs_empty) > 0:
    print(f'{len(trs_empty)=}',end='\r')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', trs_empty[0])
    time.sleep(.5)
    trs_empty = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tbody>tr[class]')
```

You can also easily scrape the table data using `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd
table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'table')
table = pd.read_html(table.get_attribute('outerHTML'))[0]
```

where `table` is the following

[image]

Comment: thx run few test and it seems to work